# Pandas multiIndex DataFrame sort

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Just show my data

```
In [14]: new_df
Out[14]: 
action_type                           1     2    3
user_id                                           
0000110e00f7c85f550b329dc3d76210   31.0   4.0  0.0
00004931fe12d6f678f67e375b3806e3    8.0   4.0  0.0
0000c2b8660766ed74bafd48599255f0    0.0   2.0  0.0
0000d8d4ea411b05e0392be855fe9756   19.0   0.0  3.0
ffff18540a9567b455bd5645873e56d5    1.0   0.0  0.0
ffff3c8cf716efa3ae6d3ecfedb2270b   58.0   2.0  0.0
ffffa5fe57d2ef322061513bf60362ff    0.0   2.0  0.0
ffffce218e2b4af7729a4737b8702950    1.0   0.0  0.0
ffffd17a96348904fe49216ba3c7006f    1.0   0.0  0.0

[9 rows x 3 columns]

In [15]: new_df.columns
Out[15]: Int64Index([1, 2, 3], dtype='int64', name=u'action_type')

In [16]: new_df.index
Out[16]: 
Index([u'0000110e00f7c85f550b329dc3d76210',
       u'00004931fe12d6f678f67e375b3806e3',
       ...
       u'ffffa5fe57d2ef322061513bf60362ff',
       u'ffffce218e2b4af7729a4737b8702950',
       u'ffffd17a96348904fe49216ba3c7006f'],
      dtype='object', name=u'user_id', length=9)
```

The output that I want is:

```
# sort by the action_type value 1

action_type                           1     2    3
user_id
ffff3c8cf716efa3ae6d3ecfedb2270b   58.0   2.0  0.0                                         
0000110e00f7c85f550b329dc3d76210   31.0   4.0  0.0
0000d8d4ea411b05e0392be855fe9756   19.0   0.0  3.0
00004931fe12d6f678f67e375b3806e3    8.0   4.0  0.0
ffff18540a9567b455bd5645873e56d5    1.0   0.0  0.0
ffffce218e2b4af7729a4737b8702950    1.0   0.0  0.0
ffffd17a96348904fe49216ba3c7006f    1.0   0.0  0.0
0000c2b8660766ed74bafd48599255f0    0.0   2.0  0.0
ffffa5fe57d2ef322061513bf60362ff    0.0   2.0  0.0

[9 rows x 3 columns]

# sort by the action_type value 2

action_type                           1     2    3
user_id
00004931fe12d6f678f67e375b3806e3    8.0   4.0  0.0
0000110e00f7c85f550b329dc3d76210   31.0   4.0  0.0
ffff3c8cf716efa3ae6d3ecfedb2270b   58.0   2.0  0.0                                         
0000c2b8660766ed74bafd48599255f0    0.0   2.0  0.0
ffffa5fe57d2ef322061513bf60362ff    0.0   2.0  0.0
0000d8d4ea411b05e0392be855fe9756   19.0   0.0  3.0
ffff18540a9567b455bd5645873e56d5    1.0   0.0  0.0
ffffce218e2b4af7729a4737b8702950    1.0   0.0  0.0
ffffd17a96348904fe49216ba3c7006f    1.0   0.0  0.0

[9 rows x 3 columns]
```

So, what I want to do is to sort the `DataFrame` by the `action_type`, that is `1, 2, 3` or the sum of any of them(`action_type` sum of `1+2, 1+3, 2+3, 1+2+3`)

The output should sorted by the value of action_type(`1, 2 or 3`) of each user or the sum of action_type(for example the sum of action_type 1 and action_type 2, and any combinations, such as the sum of action_type 1 and action_type 3, the sum of action_type 2 and action_type 3, the sum of action_type 1 and action_type 2 and action_type 3) of each user.

**For example:**

for user id `0000110e00f7c85f550b329dc3d76210`, the value of action_type 1 is 31.0, the value of action_type 2 is 4 and the value of action_type 3 is 3. The sum of action_type 1 and action_type 2 of this user is 31.0 + 4.0 = 35.0

I have tried `new_df.sortlevel()`, but it seems it has just sored the dataframe by the `user_id`, not by the `action_type(1, 2, 3)`

How can I do it, thank you!

Comment: mind posting desired output and explain what you mean by the sum of `1+2, 1+3, 2+3, 1+2+3`

Comment: @HugoHonorem, Hi, I have posted my desired output.

Comment: what is `action_type(1, 2, 3)` ?

Comment: still a little bit unclear, what is your expected output for the first 4 rows only?

Comment: @HugoHonorem, I wan to sort the dataframe. And the dataframe sorted by the action_type value, there are 3 action_type, 1, 2 and 3. I want to sorted the dataframe by the value of action_type 1 or 2 or 3. Or the sum of the value of action_type 1 and action_type 2, or the sum of the value of action_type 1 and action_type 3, or the sum of the value of action_type 1 and action_type 3, or the sum of the value of action_type 1 and action_type 2 and action_type 3. The user_ids are unique.

Comment: IMO you can't use predicate `OR` when talking about sorting - you can either sort it this way or that way

Comment: Try always to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions. In case of _pandas_ questions please provide sample _input_ and _output_ data sets (5-7 rows in CSV/dict/JSON/Python code format _as text_, so one could use it when coding an answer for you). This will help to avoid _situations_ like: `your code isn't working for me` or `it doesn't work with my data`, etc.

Comment: @MaxU, Thanks, to know more the data, I need to sort the dataframe by different ways. So, I want to sort the dataframe by differant value of action_type 1,  2 and 3.

Comment: So @MaxU 's answer is pretty much what you want with some minor modifications then..

Comment: @HugoHonorem, Sorry for not giving the correct output of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

If you wanna sort it by columns, just try [sort_values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values)

```
df.sort_values(column_names)
```

Example:

```
In [173]: df
Out[173]:
   1  2  3
0  6  3  8
1  0  8  0
2  3  8  0
3  5  2  7
4  1  2  1
```

sort descending by column `2`

```
In [174]: df.sort_values(by=2, ascending=False)
Out[174]:
   1  2  3
1  0  8  0
2  3  8  0
0  6  3  8
3  5  2  7
4  1  2  1
```

sort descending by sum of columns `2+3`

```
In [177]: df.assign(sum=df.loc[:,[2,3]].sum(axis=1)).sort_values('sum', ascending=False)
Out[177]:
   1  2  3  sum
0  6  3  8   11
3  5  2  7    9
1  0  8  0    8
2  3  8  0    8
4  1  2  1    3
```

**OLD answer:**

if i got you right, you can do it this way:

```
In [107]: df
Out[107]:
   a  b  c
0  9  1  4
1  0  5  7
2  5  9  8
3  3  9  7
4  1  2  5

In [108]: df.assign(sum=df.sum(axis=1)).sort_values('sum', ascending=True)
Out[108]:
   a  b  c  sum
4  1  2  5    8
1  0  5  7   12
0  9  1  4   14
3  3  9  7   19
2  5  9  8   22
```

Comment: Sorry for not giving correct output of the data. Your answer is correct! Thanks.

Comment: @AlexanderYau, you are very welcome! It was bit difficult to understand what do you want to achieve before you posted an examples of desired output data sets